# What are the victory conditions?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft, the rule is: "Last man standing wins the game".

So you must destroy "all buildings" to eliminate your enemy completely. That includes all floating Terran buildings,too.

But does this include Protoss Pylons, Terran Energy Depots, and Vespene Refineries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All buildings must be destroyed in order for a player to lose, see [Blizz Rules](http://sea.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/48835155?page=2#27).  Note, that this does not constitute a "win" condition, only a "lose" condition. In the event that a player hits a "lose" condition, while the other player does not, the other player THEN hits a "win" condition.

This is important because in a condition where players are racing to destroy each other buildings, the one that was destroyed quicker down to the millisecond, will trigger the "lose" condition for the first player, preventing the second one from hitting a "lose" condition, doing it this way prevents a "double win" miss-hap.

It's also important to remember that buildings in flight and mid-construction are also building units counting towards the players "not-yet-lost" condition. Units like Creep tumors are considered food-cost-less units, not buildings.

Also note, that there are "stalemate" conditions, when neither player can take such action as to cause the other player into a "lose" condition, see [Team Liquid Wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Stalemate_Detection)

Comment: Also, a player can resign.

Comment: Yes it totally consitute a "win" condition which is the negation of the "lose" condition. His lose conditoin = your win condition. See basic logic laws : https://criticalthinkeracademy.com/courses/2514/lectures/51567

Comment: @Tristan unlike paid for courses that teach condition and conditoin are the same word, the logic of StarCraft 2 takes place in a reality that is dictated by time. Your course doesn’t take time into consideration, all expressions are essentially coexisting. However, in StarCraft 2, just like real life, logical conditions are expressed via a one-by-one basis, where the existence of the first one will cause other parts of the code or reality to react to it. Code runs at 30,60 or 120 frames per second, reality runs at 1 frame per Planck second, without logic that follows in steps everything fails.

Comment: This is pure jibberish, have fun in your parallel reality though ;)

Comment: Search for this instead? gibberish

Answer (score 2):

Yes every single structure must be destroyed. With a structure being any fixed, player-controlled construct that required resources to be built. That is with minerals and/or vespene gas. This category includes all constructs with the capacity of being lifted, as they're fixed constructs that become movable should the player decide to. Even while being in the lifted state they're considered buildings. Essentially every fixed colored point you see on the minimap. Only creep tumors are some sort of structure not considered a building.

Comment: "With a structure being any fixed, player-controlled construct that required resources to be built." @rubo77 already pointed out why this would be a bad definition: Terran buildings can be lifted off the ground.

Comment: @Powerlord Huh... true, editing now.